# View Items in List Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, custom-permission-level

I'm attempting to create a Permission level with the following requirements:

- Users are able to View the Document Library's contents
- Users are not able to Save items to the Library

And another level with the requirements above and the addition of

- Users are able to upload documents, but not edit the items in the list.

I've tried creating a level with the following permissions selected:

**List Permissions**

- Add Items
- View Items
- View Application Pages

**Site Permissions**

- View Pages
- Open

but my test User was not able to see the Document Library with these permissions.

Alternatively, if there is a way to easily stop users from being able to save to the Library without configuring Permission levels, it would be preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, I can view the document content in the document library with the relevant permission level.

Whether you can view the content in other libraries?

Go to site settings->site collection features, make sure the “Limited-access user permission lockdown mode” feature is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the suggestions which you can try

1. Create a document library web part in a page(disable new item option in the webpart properties)
2. remove those user/group permission in the document library who don't want data to be add (provide unique permission)